# How can i get a Oauth 2.0 access token for firebase in my Spring app

Tags: java, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to retrieve an Oauth 2.0 access token in my Spring boot application so i can send push notification via my server. I followed [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1#generate_and_retrieve_the_access_token) but they failed to show an example of how to retrieve the token with the google client library they stated and also how to link the private key json file with it. Presently i have downloaded and saved the private key file on my system and also imported the Google API Client Library via maven. But i am stuck on how to actually use them to get a token.

Please an assistance here in terms of a code snippet will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OAuthRestTemplate, you just configure it as a bean and it will automatically get tokens as needed.

Here is one page with examples, but there are tons online depending on what type of token you are using. [OAuthRestTemplate Examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.security.oauth.consumer.client.OAuthRestTemplate)